# Any way to create a new, empty Binding in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to create a completely empty `Binding` object for use with `eval`?

According to the docs, only the `Kernel#binding` method can create new bindings. I tried something like this:

```
empty = binding
```

but then, that binding has `empty` itself among its local variables, along with any other local variables in the same scope assigned later in the code.

I discovered that the constant `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` is a binding which is empty, and which suffices for my immediate purposes. It might not always, though.

Is there any way to create a brand new, completely empty `Binding`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way would be to write a method that calls `binding` and nothing else:

```
def empty_binding
  binding
end
```

Then:

```
b = empty_binding
b.local_variables
# [ ]
```

That binding will still have a `self` and access to whatever instance variables are available to that `self`. You could limit that with some chicanery:

```
module Empty
  def self.binding
    super
  end
end

b = Empty.binding
b.eval('puts local_variables.inspect')
# [ ]
b.eval('puts instance_variables.inspect')
# [ ]
b.eval('puts self.inspect')
# Empty
```

What works depends on what the goal is. A binding with no local variables is pretty easy, a binding with nothing at all probably isn't possible without hacking Ruby itself (although `BasicObject` might be useful to get a little closer to empty than a module).

None of these things give you a jail to safely `eval` inside if that's what you're after.